# How can I enter in multiple dates in MySQL from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out a way to enter in multiple dates from a string in mysql table.

For example, if I have a string like "2012-01-17 - 2012-01-23" and the name "John Doe", I want to insert a row for every date in that range with the data "John Doe" (the only info that changes is the date)

**date_field - name_field**

2012-01-17 - John Doe

2012-01-18 - John Doe

2012-01-19 - John Doe

etc.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can break up the string with something like [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode). Then loop over the dates and `INSERT` them into the database.

Not sure how much detail you need, but that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

After separating the string into begin and end dates, you could do something along the lines of:

```
$beginDate = '2012-01-17';
$endStamp   = strtotime('2012-01-23');

// insert beginning row: 2012-01-17

// insert between dates
while ( ($date = strtotime($beginDate.' + 1 day')) < $endStamp ) {
    // insert row: date('Y-m-d', $date)
}

// insert ending row: 2012-01-23
```